# What is the best method show jpeg frames as a video?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas, jpeg, mjpeg

I get jpeg frames via a socket.io connection that are base64 encoded and currently draw them on a HTML5 canvas. This overwhelms even an i7 with a 800x600/30fps 'video' in firefox.

What is the most performant way to do this?
I tried both CSS, WebGL (via THREE.js and changing the texture) and HTML5 canvas as above. I thought it might be more performant if I actually could pass this to a video tag as an mjpeg stream, but I am lost on how I could do this clientside.

Any idea what solution would be better here?

Currently I receive an event with the data for one full frame and execute this:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + event.data;
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Does "overwhelms even an i7" mean that the CPU is too high or the memory or the network?

Comment: right, I should have been more specific. I meant CPU time spent.

Comment: If you comment out your "drawImage" command, I wonder how the CPU would react?  That might tell you if it is the decoding that is slow or the drawing.

Comment: Websockets are simply not designed to deliver ultra-heavy payloads like a mountain of pseudo-video frames. Instead, use the best tool for the job. The video element is designed to efficiently & effectively stream frames. The video element has built-in buffering and preloading that will reduce your client-side lagging. The transcoding into a video stream must be done on the server (or preferably in pre-production) because client-side transcoding would cost more resources than your currently failing method. If you can't refactor your project, the workaround is to accept fewer incoming frames.

Comment: @David the drawImage command is not the problem, it is really loading the image (onload), not sure if it is the base64 decoding or really loading the image. I did some research that said base64 decoding vs. native image loading is actually not much worse.

Comment: @markE yes, I have to live with the single frames coming in. There is no way around it. It seems that the img tag can natively display mjpeg video as well. I am wondering if can somehow push those frames as a source of that.